# List files whose content begin with a letter in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to write a bash script which lists all files in a directory (and its subdirectories) that start with a certain letter, say A/a. How can it be done if the content of the file should begin with the letter, rather than its name?

Comment: What's your question?  You've been here for almost 3 years, you should know that we don't do your work for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -rn "^[A|a]" * | awk -F: '$2==1{print $1}'
```

grep recursively(`-r`) for the pattern `^[A|a]` in the current folder. If found (need not be on the first line), grep output would look like `filname:linenumber:match`. Use `awk` with `:` as field seperator and for cases where linenumber is `1`(match found on the first line, i.e file beginning), print the `1st` field which is the filename. grep output will contain the linenumber since we r giving the `-n` option.

Answer (score 2):

With just Bash and the `globstar` option (`shopt -s globstar`) to enable `**/*`:

```
for file in **/*; do [[ $(< "$file") == [Aa]* ]] && echo "$file"; done
```

This loops through all files (and directories) recursively and checks if their content starts with `A` or `a`. If so, the filename gets printed.

It actually also tries to compare directories to `[Aa]*`, but just returns a non-successful exit status for `$(< "$file")` when `$file` is a directory.

Alternatively, without Bashsims, using `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '[ "$(head -c 1 "$1" | tr A a)" = a ]' _ {} \; -print
```

This filters for files (`-type f`), then spawns a subshell, in which the test `"$(head -c 1 "$1" | tr A a)" = a` is run (get first character of file, transpose potential uppercase `A` to `a`, compare to `a`, and if the exit status of that is successful, print the file name.